# How to call a loopback api from the server

Tags: express, loopbackjs

I'm exploring using loopback with server-side rendering.  I have the server-side rendering working except I'm scratching my head how to get a call to the server to get the data. I guess in my route I need to gain access to my model, but not sure how to do that.

In my example below, assume I created an "account" model via the slc loopback:model command.

In my root.js

```
  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
      // get account data
      // var accountData = ????

      res.render('index', {
          accountData: accountData
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why I blanked out about this one, but it was simple.

I just needed to get context like this (since server was passed in to routes):

```
var Account = server.models.Account;
```

Once I did that I could easily do a find() something like this.

```
Account.find(function(accounts,err) {
  accountData = accounts;
});
```